# Android soft keyboard keys center gravity

Tags: java, android, keyboard

I have been working on a custom keyboard but i am facing a problem that i can not figure how to solve. I am trying to aling all keys of every row in the center. I mean that even if a row has 9 or 10 or 11 keys all are alligned at center. This is what my keyboard looks like now:

http://postimg.org/image/6jy1uyd6x/

What am I doing wrong?
Here is my xml file too:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Keyboard xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:horizontalGap="1%p"
    android:verticalGap="0.4%p"
    >
    <Row android:keyWidth="9%p" android:keyHeight="75dip" android:rowEdgeFlags="top">
        <Key android:codes="49" android:keyLabel=";" android:keyEdgeFlags="left"/>
        <Key android:codes="50" android:keyLabel="ς"/>
        <Key android:codes="51" android:keyLabel="ε"/>
        <Key android:codes="52" android:keyLabel="ρ"/>
        <Key android:codes="53" android:keyLabel="τ"/>
        <Key android:codes="54" android:keyLabel="υ"/>
        <Key android:codes="55" android:keyLabel="θ"/>
        <Key android:codes="56" android:keyLabel="ι"/>
        <Key android:codes="57" android:keyLabel="ο"/>
        <Key android:codes="48" android:keyLabel="π" android:keyEdgeFlags="right"/>
    </Row>
```

This is my keyboard.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<android.inputmethodservice.KeyboardView 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/keyboard"
    android:imeOptions="flagNoFullscreen"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center|fill_horizontal"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:keyPreviewLayout ="@layout/preview"
    android:keyBackground="@drawable/key_background"
    android:keyTextSize="35sp"
    android:keyTextColor="@color/key_text_color"
    android:keyPreviewHeight="50sp"
    android:shadowRadius="1"
    android:shadowColor="#fff"
    android:padding="0px" android:layout_margin="0px"
    tools:ignore="ResAuto" />
```

I dont want to use %p cause its not the best way to make this out.
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 3):

try setting the first key  `android:keyEdgeFlags="left"` and add `android:horizontalGap="5%p"`  to it

```
<Row    >
        <Key android:codes="97" android:keyLabel="A" android:horizontalGap="5%p" 
                android:keyEdgeFlags="left"/>
        <Key android:codes="115" android:keyLabel="S"/>
        <Key android:codes="100" android:keyLabel="D"/>
        <Key android:codes="102" android:keyLabel="F"/>
        <Key android:codes="103" android:keyLabel="G"/>
        <Key android:codes="104" android:keyLabel="H"/>
        <Key android:codes="106" android:keyLabel="J"/>
        <Key android:codes="107" android:keyLabel="K"/>
        <Key android:codes="108" android:keyLabel="L" android:keyEdgeFlags="right"/>
    </Row>
```

Comment: I tried this but my keyboard keys still wont alling at center. Any other ideas? I am still breaking my head trying to find how this happens. Searching on site did not help me!

Comment: remove android:horizontalGap="1%p"  from Keyboard

Comment: Well still my keyboard persists of not alligning at center. Keys stack one one each other and they dont go in the center!!

Comment: I have created a custom keyboard  but i didn't have it yet. but i followed https://github.com/thamizha/android-tamilvisai

Comment: remove fill_horizontal status from gravity in  android.inputmethodservice.KeyboardView   . it may solve your isssue. Or try by adding layout_gravity=center in keyboardView

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I still can not figure how to fix this. This solution did not work for me.

Comment: I am facing the same problem and layout_gravity doesn't work!!

Answer (score 2):

I've found a solution that worked for me.

What Nepster suggested to you was right, except that I removed the keyEdgeFlags="right" form the last letter.

```
<Row>
<key android:label="a" codes.... android:keyEdgeFlags="left" android:horizontalGap="5%p"/>
<key "s" .../>
<key "d" .../>
....
<key android:label="l" codes ... />
```

This is giving me this layout:

[image: this is only one of my example just compiled]